# Set up a guest machine in VirtualBox to use a given static IP address

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox

My company recently assigned some static IPs to everyone and required everyone to use it to access internal network. On top of the static IP, the internal network must be accessed through a software called AnyOffice, which works on Windows but not Linux.

I am a Linux user so I wonder if there is a way to use a guest Windows machine in VirtualBox to access the network so I can still get most things done in my Linux host.

I have done some googling and found most answers not suitable because the static address assigned by VirtualBox to the guest is always something like '192.168.x.y'.

Here are some main challenges here:

1. The guest needs to use a static IP address;
2. The IP address is given, which means the static address is not arbitrary;
3. The connection has to be established on Windows because AnyOffice does not provide a Linux version.

Although I can just use a Windows host with a linux guest to solve the problem, I am very used to Linux now and so I prefer using linux as a host. Is this possible?

Comment: what do you mean your company assigned static IPs?  are you a remote worker?

Comment: Are you able to get more than one static IP address assigned to you?  If so, you can use bridged networking for your Windows guest.

Comment: @Keltari I am not a remote worker. The company gives each one of the staff a static IP to use at the workplace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VirtualBox networking options are somewhat confusingly named, but there is an option called [Bridged Networking](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_bridged) that, unlike the name suggests, doesn't use a bridge, but instead access the host network adapter directly.

So this is similar to a Linux `macvlan`, and it means you can give your guest WM a static IP. Note that this static IP must be different from the static IP of your Linux host, so you should make sure you got at least two static IP addresses assigned from your company (then you can assign one to your Linux host), *OR* you need to make sure that Linux doesn't use the physical network interface by not assigning any static or dynamic IP to add.

The second problem is configuring the Linux host to use the Windows guest for networking. For that, you need a second network interface in virtual box in [host-only](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly) mode, you must configure Linux to use this network interface as default route, and you must configure Windows to NAT connections from this network interface ("Share an Internet connection", in Windows terms). I have no idea if this will work together with AnyOffice or not.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. It turns out you only need one static IP and do not need a separate host-only network interface.

For future reference, here are some key steps:

1. Create a bridged adapter with the highest priority (meaning that it's the first enabled adapter in the network panel shown below);
2. Select the wired physical adapter (in my example, this would be `enp2s0`; you can check yours with the `ifconfig` command).
3. Set promiscuous mode to `Allow All`.
4. Set the MAC Address of your wired physical adapter (also with the `ifconfig` command); this step should be required when the static IP is bound to a specific MAC Address.
   [image]
5. On the windows guest, configure network connection to use the static IP; now the guest should be able to connect to the internet.
   [image]
6. If you also want to use the static IP on your linux host, set it up in network manager and connect (keep the connection in your windows host open).
   [image]